# does google data studio/looker studio support window function?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I want to do cumulative sum on a column of a blended data source, like SQL window function.
I want to ask if it is possible on Google data studio or not. Or I must create a BigQuery view to do cumulative count then use it as a data studio data source?
[image]

EDIT:
The situation is:

We have a table looks like:

```
due_date               amount
2018-01-05T00:00:00    99.0
2018-02-15T00:00:00    70.0
2018-02-15T00:00:00    90.0
2018-03-17T00:00:00    20.0
2018-03-17T00:00:00    10.0
```

My goal is to create a report that show the cumulative sum of amount day by day, so I create a BigQuery view like this:

```
select tmp.due_date, sum(tmp.amount) over(order by tmp.due_date) as cumulative_amount
                                from (select due_date, sum(amount)
                                        from `bigquery.table` join
                                        `bigquery.another` on ...
                                        where due_date is not null  
                                group by due_date order by due_date) as tmp
```

It will return

```
due_date               sum
2018-01-05T00:00:00    99.0
2018-02-15T00:00:00    259.0
2018-03-17T00:00:00    289.0
```

But the user want to have a date range control on `due_date`, for example the choose the date range from `2018-02-15` to `2018-03-17`, my report (based on that view) will show:

```
due_date               sum
2018-02-15T00:00:00    259.0
2018-03-17T00:00:00    289.0
```

But they expect:

```
due_date               sum
2018-02-15T00:00:00    160.0
2018-03-17T00:00:00    190.0
```

They want the first 99.0 will not be added to below results
So my first idea is to change the view (remove the sum over (order by)):

```
select due_date, sum(amount)
                                            from `bigquery.table` join
                                            `bigquery.another` on ...
                                            where due_date is not null  
                                    group by due_date order by due_date
```

It will only do the summing day by day, and the sum over (order by) will be move to data studio, then the date range control will take effect.
But i'm not sure data studio support window functions or not. Please help

Comment: Short version there is no window function in blend. You can use a custom query to BigQuery to use window functions. Another walkaround for some cases is to use the blend and add the same again (adding another join). Please provide all information then, because `count(FieldA) over (order by field_B)` does not make any sense.

Comment: I edited my post, kindly check and give your idea. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to show a running sum in any table:

Please click on the "SUM" symbol:

[image]

and select the runnin sum:

[image]

Or you could include the start and end dates in the BigQuery View (custom Query):

```
select 
  tmp.due_date,
  sum(tmp.amount) over(order by tmp.due_date) as cumulative_amount
    from 
    (
      select due_date, sum(amount)
        from `bigquery.table` join  `bigquery.another` on ...
        where date(due_date ) between PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) and PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
        group by due_date order by due_date
     ) as tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is @DS_START_DATE? Where does it come from?

Comment: The `@DS_START_DATE` is the start date, in looker studio this given in the custom query, if you select include data range as parameters.

Comment: Your solution about running sum works, thank you. Btw, could you provide me a link of document about custom query?

Comment: doc for custom query : https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10588439?hl=en